# How does one cook Banh Su Xue?

Tags: baking, cake, frozen

I just got this from the Asian supermarket:

[image: Banh Su Xue]

It says on the back "product requires cooking before consuming!", but nothing else.  How does one cook frozen Ban Su Xue?

Comment: Somebody asked a pretty identical question to yours here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.food.asian/rUrwjMzLtgU and looking at the ingredients on your package, it sounds pretty similar to http://rasamalaysia.com/kuih-dadar-kuih-tayap/ which would make me think that yes, probably eat it at room temperature like the first link said.

Comment: The label might give great info. Can you show us both sides of that? At this point, I suspect that those are filled with mung bean paste or similar. If that is correct, steaming those packets is likely your best option.

Comment: Check out this video which I found from a Google search for "Ban Su Xue". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0GJbNMN7BU&t=308s I can see in your picture something that looks like a filling very much like the cakes in the video. I strongly suspect that these are very similar cakes. I leave this as a comment instead of an answer because I'm really just guessing. Let us know!

Comment: @Setek: the package says it needs cooking, and it doesn't look at all similar to the pictures in the link you posted :/ I think the answerer on that Google thread was just wrong.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: The label only has nutritional information on the back :/ I'll check the video.

Comment: I am suspecting that this is translation issue. I am wondering if  the phrase "product requires cooking before consuming" is actually  implying that the product has not been cooked already. just a guess.  I also watched the video when saw this question first asked and my thought was the packed product looks like it has already been steamed. Open the package and see if it holds it shape. Uncooked or un steamed it would be a gelatinous pudding type of consistency. break one open. finding someone who speaks Vietnamese  would be a good idea. take it with you to a Pho restaurant and ask the server.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your photo but if the báhn xu xê cakes were cooked, the outer green part would be fairly translucent since it's mainly composed of tapioca flour. Tapioca cooks clear. Yours looks cloudy still.

Báhn xu xê cakes are steamed for 15 minutes and then cooled. I've seen places where they're steamed in plastic wraps and I suppose that's safe but not what I'd consider appetizing. I honestly can't say how well they would hold together without some kind of wrapping while steaming. Traditionally, they were wrapped in pandan leaf folded into a box shape. Pandan leaves are used for flavouring as well as wrapping. My best suggestion is to rewrap them in double thickness parchment baking paper if you don't wish to use plastic wrap and tie with string to hold together. The paper will get soggy, of course, but should hold their shape.

By the way,  báhn xu xê translates as "husband-wife cakes" and is traditionally served at weddings.